# error :Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable' android studio 3.0

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a simple XML for calculator with no Java code yet
the image extenssion is .png, the sdk version is 27 and here is the button_shape xml file 
I faced such this problem many times even when I download something from github and just import it.
here is the main XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/resul_background"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSolution"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:padding="2sp"
        android:paddingTop="5sp"
        android:textSize="15pt"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:padding="2sp"
        android:paddingTop="5sp"
        android:textSize="15pt"
        android:text="@string/zero"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:columnCount="4">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnClear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shap2"
            android:text="@string/clear"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shap"
            android:text="@string/square"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPercent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shap"
            android:text="@string/percent"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBracet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shap"
            android:text="@string/praket"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSeven"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shap"
            android:text="@string/seven"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shap"
            android:text="@string/eight"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNine"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shap"
            android:text="@string/nine"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDivide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shap"
            android:text="@string/divide"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnFour"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shap"
            android:text="@string/four"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnFive"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shap"
            android:text="@string/five"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSix"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shap"
            android:text="@string/six"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMultiply"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shap"
            android:text="@string/multiply"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnOne"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shap"
            android:text="@string/one"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shap"
            android:text="@string/two"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnThree"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shap"
            android:text="@string/three"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSubtract"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shap"
            android:text="@string/minus"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDecimal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shap"
            android:text="@string/dot"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnZero"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shap"
            android:text="@string/zero"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEquals"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shap"
            android:text="@string/equal"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shap"
            android:text="@string/plus"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"/>


    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

`

I am using Android Studio 3.0 and I get this error:

```
01-30 21:59:40.876 11456-11456/com.example.dell.calculator2 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering***
```

the image extenssion is .png, the sdk version is 27 and here is the button_shape xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<gradient
android:startColor="#307D7E"
android:endColor="#C7EBF9"
android:angle="45">
</gradient>

<corners
android:radius="7dp">
</corners>

<padding
android:bottom="5dp"
android:left="5dp"
android:right="5dp"
android:top="7dp">
</padding>

<stroke
android:color="#ffff"
android:width="4dp">
</stroke>
```

Comment: what is the extension of  your drawable image

Comment: This XML is not related to the crash. Your problem is somewhere else (maybe in the background `@drawable/button_shap` or `@drawable/resul_background` referenced?)

Comment: in case of using a custom drawable for the background, please,  add it.

Comment: can you please provide detail for sdk version from your app gradle and ripple effect file

Comment: once I remove both of the result background and the button shape from the xml the activity runs fine, however if I keep one of them it crash :/

Comment: Please help me guys !

Comment: Someone help me please !

Comment: Are you placing numbers above these backgrounds instead of strings?

Comment: Can you create an example with one button and your button shape drawable and see what happens?

Comment: Im using numbers of course but as String and yes I did try to keep only one button with button shape drawable I got the same error :(